# Java on Macintosh directoryStream shows Applications as Folders

Tags: java, macos, directory, directorystream, simplefilevisitor

I feel like I must be missing something.  It seems like this should be really easy but I can't seem to find an answer to this question.

I'm writing code in Java 8 using both

> Files.newDirectoryStream()
>
> class SimpleFileVisitor() {}

On a Macintosh (OSX 10.9.5) the Application Folder shows all the applications as a directory with a generated name and the code tells me it's a directory.  I would like it to work like it does in the `FileSelectDialog()`.  I am aware that under the hood and in the terminal applications really ARE just directories. The output to my code ends up looking like this.

[image]

I want to treat Applications like they do in the `FileSelectDialog()` and in the Mac Browser and have them looks like an application.  Ie notice it's an application and treat it and is subdirectories & files as one application. But I can't figure out what I'm missing.

> Default apdflckaaahabafndbhieahigkjhalf.app

Should look like

> Google Drive.app

Would `Files.isTraversable()` help?
I can just look for the .app extension but I'm not sure that is 100% reliable.

Comment: Look for both Files.isTraversible and the .app extension

Comment: Well it's FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().isTraversable() and that doesn't help.  I suppose I can just look at the .app extension.  Still not sure how to get the 'real' name.

Comment: Testing for .app extension does work for my current examples.  But I still get this extremely long generated name rather than the real one.  Any idea's how to find the real name.